# How to get the label of dropdown in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to get the label of a dropdown list (Eg:**Inventory Part,Non-Inventory Part** ..) from the dropdownlist
 The code for dropdown list is

```
<select value={'ItemType'}  onChange={this.handleChange}  style={{'width':'448px'}}>
                     <option value='0'>Select An Item Type</option>
                     <option value='1'>**Inventory Part**</option>
                     <option value='2'>**Non-Inventory Part**</option> 
                     <option value='3'>Other Change</option>
                     <option value='4'>Subtotal</option>
                     <option value='5'>Group</option> 
                     <option value='6'>Discount</option> 
                     <option value='7'>Payment</option>
                     <option value='8'>Sales Tax Item</option>
                     <option value='9'>Sales Tax Group</option>
                    </select>
```

The handleChange function and constructor is as follows:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={type:''}
  }
handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({type:e.target.value});
  };
```

How can I modify my *handleChange* so that I get the labels of the options?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding a new state 'label' holding the label

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={type:'', label: ''}
}      
handleChange = (e) => {
    let index = e.nativeEvent.target.selectedIndex;
    let label = e.nativeEvent.target[index].text;
    let value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ type: value, label: label});
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this

```
var index = e.nativeEvent.target.selectedIndex;
var text =e.nativeEvent.target[index].text;
console.log(text);
```

Your handle change method

```
handleChange = (e) => {

   var index = e.nativeEvent.target.selectedIndex;
  var text =e.nativeEvent.target[index].text;
console.log(text);
    this.setState({type:e.target.value});

  };
```

Here is the demo of it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ymwpeu

Answer (score 2):

The best way is by generating the dropdown's values from data that has what you need:

```
const itemTypes = {
  "0": "Select An Item Type",
  "1": "Inventory Part",
  "2": "Non-Inventory Part",
  "3": "Other Change",
  "4": "Subtotal",
  "5": "Group",
  "6": "Discount",
  "7": "Payment",
  "8": "Sales Tax Item",
  "9": "Sales Tax Group",
};

class Component extends React.Component {
  // ...

  handleChange = e => {
    const itemTypeId = e.target.value;
    const itemTypeText = itemTypes[itemTypeId];
    console.log(itemTypeText); // Do what you need to with the value here
    this.setState({ type: itemTypeId });
  };

  // ...

  render() {
    return (
      <select
        value="ItemType"
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        style={{ width: "448px" }}
      >
        {Object.keys(itemTypes).map(typeId => (
          <option value={typeId}>{itemTypes[typeId]}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `innerText` property from the event nativeEvent target object, no need for using state:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  const { innerText } = e.nativeEvent.target
  // innerText will have the label of the selected option
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Visit below link for multiselect dropdown

https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get only label of selected option, then it will be very simple.

```
   <option value="Inventory Part">**Inventory Part**</option>
```

and your handle change will remain same.

```
   let index = e.nativeEvent.target.selectedIndex;
   let label = e.nativeEvent.target[index].text;
```